# Minimum number of moves a chess piece has to do in order to pass through all squares of a 8x8 board from an X position.

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

I need to know what is the minimum number of moves a chess piece has to do from an X position to pass through all squares of a board. Mathmatic and programming solutions are welcome. I need because I am working on an essay about chess.
EDIT: THE BOARD ONLY CONTAINS THE PIECE TO BE TESTED.

Comment: Could you specify the allowed moves in this question? Also, we would like to see what attempt you have done to tackle this question.

Comment: For the knight, knight moves; for the queen, queen moves, and so on. In this case let's suppose Knight starts as white in house b1, so I want to know how many moves he can make from take house in such way he passes through all positions in the minimal number of moves. By the way, I am noob at mathmatics. Sorry. I tried manually doing that but it doesn't seem a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Please try not to post PSQs on Math SE

### Hint

[image]

Comment: For the queen, king and tower there is a better approach.

Comment: I think you cannot complete it in fewer than 5 moves

Comment: I made an edit: The board has only the piece to be tested.